# Don't execute the before test code for every test without using a before all block

Tags: ruby, rspec, automated-tests

I want to execute some before code and test the result with multiple it statements without having to run the before code.

```
context 'context A' do
   context 'context A.1' do
     before(:each) do
        # Doing a lot of things and using let variables,...
     end

     it 'T1: test thing 1'
     it 'T2: test thing 2'
     it 'T3: test thing 3'
  end

  context 'context B.1' do
     before(:each) do
        # Doing a lot of things and using let variables,...
     end

     it 'T1: test thing 1'
     it 'T2: test thing 2'
     it 'T3: test thing 3'
  end
end
```

If you look to the execution it looks something like:

> before A.1 - T1 - before A.1 - T2 - before A.1 - T3 - before B.1 - T1 - ...

But i want:

> before A.1 - T1 - T2 - T3 - before B.1 - T1 - T2 - T3

I tried to use a before(:all) but i cannot use it because i use a lot of let variables. You get following error because a let should change in every context.

> RuntimeError: let declaration `var1` accessed in a `before(:context)` hook at:

I could combine all tests in one it statement but i don't want that, i want to see which particalur test fails. The only solution i see is to get rid of all the let variables but this wil result in a massive block of instance variables and in a lot of different test files resulting in a lot of duplicate code...

Can i get the behaviour i want in an other way? Or do i have to look at things in another way?

Comment: i don't see why removing the `let` variables (replacing them with instance variables) would cause the line length to increase. Defining an instance variable takes no more space than a `let`

Comment: That is true, i should have said a lot of instance variables should be declared in the document and in a lot of other test files. Which i don't like because it is a lot of duplicate code and more maintenance if something changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but i don't want that, i want to see which particalur test fails.

That is the only thing that prevents you from doing this? Easy.

```
   context 'context A.1' do
     before(:each) do
        # Doing a lot of things and using let variables,...
     end

     it 'test all the things', aggregate_failures: true do
       ... 
     end

  end
```

You can even enable it globally for all specs in your `spec_helper.rb` (that's what I do).